# Media previews on posts

Tags: themes, media, embed

*Firstly a quick disclaimer - I'm fairly inexperienced when it comes to WordPress. I'm a programmer by profession but don't work with PHP or wordpress a lot.*

I've just done a theme change on a blog that is linked to our actual site - for a number of reasons.

Anyway - the old theme had a preview if there was media from SoundCloud or Youtube (and probably other media platforms) with custom tags, eg:

```
[soundcloud url="https://api.soundcloud.com/xyz" width="100%" height="450" iframe="true" /]
```

or

```
<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/xxx"></iframe>
```

Would appear in the post preview as a soundcloud embed item with the post's text below it.

However, on the new theme the previews don't appear, and when open the single post version of the posts there is also no play option of the media.
The old theme was Blogoma and the new one is Radiate (the free version).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out what was happening - either the new theme or an unintentional wordpress update, lead to media links being handled differently. My new theme now only needs the URL - no shortcodes or iframes - and it seems to automatically process it to display how it used to display them.

Only issue with this is that the old posts have to be edited to reflect the change.

Comment: Processing shortcodes should not be done by themes, but by plugins. Apart from the theme did you change any plugins?

Comment: Nope - however there was a wordpress upgrade to 4.5.2 from an older version (can't find the version number though).